# cocoa: how to easily add a new view to split view

Tags: cocoa

when I add a new table view to a split view by Interface Builder, I need to resize the table view by drag the table edge to fill the split view completely. I'm wondering how to do this easier than dragging?
[image]

what I want is:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand You correctly I think You want this:

Select added table view and go to **Size Inspector** -> **Arrange** -> and select:

1) **Fill Container Horizontally** - it will fill completely horizontally selected View.

2) **Fill Container Vertically** - it will fill vertically.

[image: Screenshot]

**Note:** To use this Auto Layout need to be disabled in **File Inspector**.

**Result:**

Before:

[image: Screenshot 2]

After pressed **Fill Container Horizontally**:

[image: Screenshot 3]

Comment: What version of Xcode are you using? I also need to find this. But my Size inspector looks different. Im using XCode 4.3. I do not see the arrange section as shown in your screen shots

Comment: @user76859403 You need to turn of **Auto Layout** in **File Inspector**. Do this: select Your window and go to **File Inspector** -> And there You will find checkbox **Use Auto Layout** uncheck it. Now You will have it.

Comment: Thank you so much, it's what I want!!